# Why "123".split('') is not equal to [1, 2, 3].join('').split('')

Tags: javascript

This appears as a very basic question, but couldn't find any explanations on SO.

Consider this:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var str = "123";

function compare(){
  return arr.join('').split('') === str.split('')
}

console.log(compare());
console.log(arr.join('').split(''))
console.log(str.split(''))
```

Cant understand why console logs `false`...?

Comment: You can not compare object like that

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: In JavaScrip, array is object. Although the contents are same, they are different objects.

Comment: Thanks everyone - God bless you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You compare two objects' references, not their content. Because you have 2 different objects, their references are not equal.

`===` with reference types will return `true` if 2 variables refer to the same object. In the below example both `a` and `b` refer to the same object (*same part in the memory*), so they are equal.

```js
const a = {};
const b = a; // assign `a`'s value, which is a reference to the `b`

console.log(a === b);
```

Answer (score 4):

Because although the two arrays you're comparing are *equivalent*, they are not the **same** array. `==` (and `===`) with objects checks to see if they're the **same object**.

What you have, in effect, is:

```js
console.log(["1", "2", "3"] == ["1", "2", "3"]);
```

Comment: Oh, right, the references are different. Now I get it. It wasn't my fault - my brain's sensory neurons did that

Answer (score 0):

They are not same array & they are separate object reference. If you want to compare these two , then stringify them

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var str = "123";

function compare() {
  return (arr.join('').split('')).toString() === str.split('').toString()
}

console.log(compare());
console.log(arr.join('').split(''))
console.log(str.split(''))
```